# MVC create view current user

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am currently working on a MVC project. In the MVC I currently have a login functionality where a users can login with his LogonName and LogonPassword.

This works fine!

In a create view I have a users can create a content item. Also in the create view I have a editorfor box in which all user accounts are shown. I want to make it so that the currently loggen in user shows in the box and not a list of all the users.

My table containing the users is called Users

Hopefully you guys can help me!!

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` for identity

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand question well. But i think you need write sql using session

Comment: Are you using Login control?

Comment: I remember that you can get user's name in login class. But it was unavailable to know user in some other form. So i saved user /*primary key*/ in session

Comment: Session["email"] = Login1.UserName;

Comment: @cihy2k, if you have not understand the question, you should have asked clarification in question rather then answering!